# cypher PROFILE via neo4j REST API

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Can anyone tell me how to run a PROFILE'd query using teh neo4j REST API such as

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:LABEL) return n;
```

When I run this either in Java using the RestCypherQueryEngine or the even using a raw HTTP post directly I get

```
  message: "Invalid input 'P': expected SingleStatement (line 1, column 1) "PROFILE MATCH (n:LABEL) return n;" ^"
exception: "SyntaxException"
```

I though I had read somewhere that this is possible not only through the server console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old cypher endpoint (i.e /db/data/cypher) had a ?profile=true query parameter that adds profiling information to the result.

e.g.

```
curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json 
     -d'{"query":"MATCH (n) RETURN count(*)","params":{}}' 
     http://localhost:7474/d/data/cypher?profile=true

{
  "columns" : [ "count(*)" ],
  "data" : [ [ 0 ] ],
  "plan" : {
    "args" : {
      "returnItemNames" : [ "count(*)" ],
      "_rows" : 1,
      "_db_hits" : 0,
      "symKeys" : [ "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE75acebd9-82d7-4a65-921c-2049c4bde4e7" ]
    },
    "dbHits" : 0,
    "name" : "ColumnFilter",
    "children" : [ {
      "args" : {
        "keys" : [ ],
        "_rows" : 1,
        "aggregates" : [ "(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE75acebd9-82d7-4a65-921c-2049c4bde4e7,CountStar())" ],
        "_db_hits" : 0
      },
      "dbHits" : 0,
      "name" : "EagerAggregation",
      "children" : [ {
        "args" : {
          "_rows" : 0,
          "_db_hits" : 0,
          "identifier" : "n"
        },
        "dbHits" : 0,
        "name" : "AllNodes",
        "children" : [ ],
        "rows" : 0
      } ],
      "rows" : 1
    } ],
    "rows" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Unfortunately I dont think the existing implementations of RestCypherQueryEngine support extracting the db_hits parameter so Ill probably have to write my own POST and extract from JSOn in java

Comment: Ya but that shouldn't be an issue :)

Comment: Just be aware that profile in cypher is experimental: it's not documented and not supported, because it's almost certainly going to change in the near future.